# different float precision using random on python 2.6 vs python 2.7

Tags: python, random, floating-point-precision

Why is there a different precision when using Random.random() in Python 2.6 and Python 2.7

example:

```
import random
import sys

rng = random.Random(0)

print sys.version
for i in range(10):
    print repr(rng.random())
```

> 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
>   0.84442185152504812
>   0.75795440294030247
>   0.420571580830845
>
> 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
>   0.8444218515250481
>   0.7579544029403025
>   0.420571580830845

Why is there a different precision? Might this be because of this changes:
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error

> In versions prior to Python 2.7 and Python 3.1, Python rounded this
>   value to 17 significant digits, giving ‘0.10000000000000001’. In
>   current versions, Python displays a value based on the shortest
>   decimal fraction that rounds correctly back to the true binary value,
>   resulting simply in ‘0.1’.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numbers returned by `random()` are the same. It's the *display* precision that's different.

Here are the first two numbers returned by my Python 2.7, but displayed to significantly more decimal digits that the default:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import random
>>> rng = random.Random(0)
>>> '%.50f' % rng.random() 
'0.84442185152504811718188193481182679533958435058594'
>>> '%.50f' % rng.random() 
'0.75795440294030247407874867349164560437202453613281'
```

If you round these to 17 decimal places, you'd get exactly the same numbers as you're getting from Python 2.6.

Comment: Not everything is what it `appears` to be ;)

Comment: py27: 0.84442185152504811718188193481182679533958435058594 
py26: 0.84442185152504812000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: I could round it yes, but i have a library that uses the random module and get in rare cases different behavior for certain seeds when using python 2.6 vs python 2.7

Comment: I think the floats are not the same in 2.6 and 2.7. There have been made quite some changes in 2.7 (u can read up here: http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/whatsnew/2.7.html its mentioned right on the top). And these changes are used in Python 3.x. Python 3.4.0a3: 0.84442185152504811718188193481182679533958435058594

Comment: After some testing i found out that my problem actually was that i was using python 2.6 32bit vs python 2.7 64bit. I guess since float in python is a C float which on 64bit has a higher precision. On 32bit i get the same behavior of the random module for both versions of python.